# What do the red telephone and blue telephone mean in iOS Xcode Instruments?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, instruments

I tried to find a legend for these graphics and colors, but I couldn't find anything that was certainly referring to this instrument.  Does anyone know?  Specifically, the blue and red telephones, the red lollipop and the black line with red stripes.  What do they all mean?

[image]

Comment: What instrument are you referring to? Does clicking on the telephone and lollipop icons make anything pop up in Instruments that provides additional information?

Comment: This is the system activity instrument.  I *think* the red means that the thread went through the security check to call a sys level function and that was a opportunity for context switching?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that the red and blue telephone icons are kernel event messages, and the other icon is a red alarm bell which indicates kernel interrupts.  If you click on those icons you will see a popup with specific details.

I checked in my project and the red telephones always corresponded to BSC_* events while blue telephones corresponded to MSC_* events.

The events list for the XNU/MacOS kernel are listed here:
https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/10.10/bsd/kern/trace.codes

I don't know what BSC means vs. MSC (maybe someone else can answer that?) but it appears to me that MSC is a generic low level event message trap such as MSC_mach_msg_trap, while BSC is more specific high level events such as BSC_gettimeofday.